# Why Java is returning Error when Regex is totally working?

Tags: java, regex

Totally working here:

```
{"air_date":"(.*)-.*-.*","episodes|(?:episode_|\G)number":(.*?),
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/_XzjcR4M3Qbdlxpu)

Java returns: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: null` in the line `episodios.add(...)`

```
    [...]

    Matcher filter = Pattern.compile("\\{\"air_date\":\"(.*)-.*-.*\",\"episodes|(?:episode_|\\G)number\":(.*?),").matcher(response);

    while (filter.find()) {
        episodios.add(new Episodio(idSerie, temporada, Integer.parseInt(filter.group(2))));
    }
}
```

Where response is: http://pastebin.com/m4EJ1iP5

I know it's JSON, and Regex isn't optimal. But it's required (teacher)!

Comment: Why do you use regex instead of Json parser?

Comment: the value of group(2) is 'null' this can be seen from the Exception.

Comment: `(.*?)` means exactly the same thing as `(.*)`.  Also, if you use single quotes `'` around the entire expression, then you won't have to escape all the double quotes `"` inside the expression: `compile('\\{"air_date":"(.*)-.*-.*","episodes|(?:episode_|\\G)number":(.*?),')`

Comment: This is Java, not Javascript. Single quotes are for Character literals only, not strings.

Comment: You could use `\d*` which will match only numbers instead of `.*`.

Comment: @JimGarrison I'm not familiar with Javascript, but I'll take your word for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in your [debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/_XzjcR4M3Qbdlxpu) first match of your regex is

```
{"air_date":"2009-03-08","episodes
```

so you have only match in group 1 (`2009`-03-08 part) but group 2 is empty (which represents `null`) and since you are passing that `null` to `Integer.parseInt` yo are getting `NumberFormatException: null`. To be sure that you are handling match for episodes

```
episode_number":1,
```

test if value of group 2 isn't `null` like

```
    while (filter.find()) {
        if (filter.group(1) != null) {
            this.ano = Integer.parseInt(filter.group(1));
        }
        if (filter.group(2) != null) {
            episodios.add(new Episodio(idSerie, temporada, Integer.parseInt(filter.group(2))));
        }
    }
```

---

But in real world you shouldn't parse JSon with regex, but with proper parser like GSon, Jackson. Here is example of how you can do it with GSon.

```
String data = new Scanner(new File("input.txt")).useDelimiter("\\A").next();

Gson gson = new Gson();
Season season = gson.fromJson(data, Season.class);

//test
System.out.println(season.getName());
System.out.println("-------");
for (Episode ep : season.getEpisodes())
    System.out.println(ep.getEpisode_number()+"\t"+ep.getName());
```

Output:

```
Season 2
-------
1   Seven Thirty-Seven
2   Grilled
3   Bit by a Dead Bee
4   Down
5   Breakage
6   Peekaboo
7   Negro Y Azul
8   Better Call Saul
9   4 Days Out
10  Over
11  Mandala
12  Phoenix
13  ABQ
```

---

used classes

```
public class Episode {

    private String air_date;
    private Integer episode_number;
    private String name;
    private String overview;
    private String still_path;
    private Double vote_average;
    private Integer vote_count;
    //getters & setters
}
```

```
public class Season {

    private String air_date;
    private List<Episode> episodes = new ArrayList<Episode>();
    private String name;
    private String overview;
    private Integer id;
    private String poster_path;
    private Integer season_number;
    private String additionalProperties;

    //getters & setters
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I DO KNOW about Gson, but my **** teacher said that is PROHIBITED anything that isn't in java.*. And correction, I should encapsule both in if, `this.ano` and `episodios.add()`